# How to clone a cloud machine locally?

Tags: linux, cloud, clone

Earlier when we are using AWS, we used to create an ami and download that hard disk file to create a new machine from it.

Recently, we changed to other local cloud services which doesn't have this feature.

So tried using vmware vcenter converter.

For windows OS,we are getting option to keep the destination as vmware workstation and save the machine with vmx and other project files, which we can open in vmware workstation.

For linux, it is not giving any option to chang ethe destination, only destination available is esxi servers and getting below error during progress.

[error of esxi conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynot1.png)

Any suggestions on a simple way to clone a cloud VM and store locally for testing purposes?

Comment: Take a look at packer.io to do this the other way round. Configure machine-images and deploy them locally or in the cloud. Maybe this helps you?

Comment: packer.io is useful for customizing existing images for AWS.But I don't think it will create images from scratch or other smaller vendors of cloud